# Show that if $X \succeq Y$, then $\det{(X)}\ge\det{(Y)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant, positive-definite

> Assume that two symmetric positive definite matrices $X$ and $Y$ are such
>   that $X-Y$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. Show that $$\det{(X)}\ge\det{(Y)}$$

I felt this result is clear, but I can't use mathematics methods explain this why?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ can be simultaneously diagonalized $X = V\Lambda V^T, Y = V\Sigma V^T$,
$$v_i^T X v_i \ge v_i^T Y v_i \Rightarrow \lambda_i \ge \sigma_i \Rightarrow \det X = \prod_i \lambda_i \ge \prod_i \sigma_i = \det Y$$
It remains the case where $X$ and $Y$ can't be simultaneously diagonalized, i.e. $XY\ne YX$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lemma 1** If $A$ is positive semi-definite, then $\det(A + I) \ge 1$.

> Proof: Since $A$ is positive semi-definite, there exists an orthogonal matrix $S$ and
>   a diagonal matrix $D$ whose entries are non-negative such that $A = SDS^{-1}$. 
>   Since $A + I = S(D + I)S^{-1}$ and $D +I$ is a diagonal matrix whose eigenvalues 
>   are all $\ge 1$, $\det(A+I) = \det(D+I) \ge 1$.

**Lemma 2** If $B$ is positive definite, $B$ has a positive definite square root.

> Proof: Since $B$ is positive definite, there exists an orthogonal matrix $T$ and a
>   digonal matrix $E$ whose diagonal entries are positive such that $B = TET^{-1}$.
>   Let $E^{1/2}$ be the diagonal matrix whose entries are positive square roots of those of $E$. It is easy to check $T E^{1/2} T^{-1}$ is positive define and $(T E^{1/2} T^{-1})^2 = B$.

By Lemma 2, $Y$ has a positive definite square root. Let us call it $R$.
We have

$$\det(X) = \det(R (R^{-1}XR^{-1}) R )
= \det(R)^2 \det(R^{-1}XR^{-1})\\
= \det(Y) \det( (R^{-1}(X-Y)R^{-1} + I )$$

It is easy to see $X - Y$ positive semi-definite implies $R^{-1} (X-Y) R^{-1}$  positive semi-definite. By Lemma 1, we have $\det( R^{-1}(X-Y)R^{-1} + I ) \ge 1$ and we are done.

Comment: Wa,Nice,I found you answer always Nice!+1

Comment: Hello,if $X,Y$ not such is symmetric ,then maybe have counter-example?

Comment: @chinamath what do you mean? a real positive definite/semi-definite matrix is symmetric, that's part of the definition.

Comment: 我的意思如果去掉X,Y是对称的,其他条件都保留,是否还是成立的呢

Comment: So you mean given two real matrices $X, Y$ whose symmetric parts $\frac12 (X + X^T)$, $\frac12 ((X-Y) + (X-Y)^T)$ are positive definite/semi-definite in the usual sense. Is it still true $\det(X) \ge \det(Y)$?

Comment: Hello,I meaning this: Assume that  two  positive definite matrices $X$ and $Y$ are such
that $X-Y$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.

show that
$$\det{(X)}\ge\det{(Y)}$$

Comment: @chinamath What is your definition of "positive definite" matrix? There is no consensus about what that is when it is not symmetric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20186/discussion-between-china-math-and-achille-hui).

Answer (score 6):

Eigenvalues only complicate this problem.

The question asks for a proof of $\det\left(Y+Z\right) \geq \det Y$ where $Y$ is a positive definite $n\times n$-matrix and $Z$ is a positive semidefinite $n\times n$-matrix. (My $Z$ is your $X-Y$.)

Write $Y$ as $U^T U$ for $U$ an invertible square matrix (this is possible since $Y$ is positive definite), and write $Z$ as $U^T V U$ for $V$ a positive semidefinite matrix (this is possible since we can take $V = \left(U^{-1}\right)^T Z U^{-1}$). Then, what we want to prove rewrites as $\det\left(U^T U + U^T V U\right) \geq \det\left(U^T U\right)$. In other words, what we want to prove rewrites as $\left(\det U\right)^2 \det\left(I_n + V\right) \geq \left(\det U\right)^2$. After cancelling $\left(\det U\right)^2$, this becomes $\det\left(I_n + V\right) \geq 1$. But $\det\left(I_n + V\right)$ is the sum of all principal minors of $V$ (to see this, recall the formula for the characteristic polynomial of $V$ in terms of its principal minors, and substitute $-1$ into this characteristic polynomial). One of these principal minors is the $0\times 0$-minor $1$, while all others are nonnegative (since $V$ is positive semidefinite). Hence, their sum is $\geq 1$, which is precisely what we needed to show.

When $n > 0$, this argument actually shows the stronger claim $\det\left(I_n + V\right) \geq 1 + \det V$ (since $\det V$, too, is a principal minor -- namely, the $n\times n$ minor), which translates back into $\det\left(Y+Z\right) \geq \det Y + \det Z$. By continuity, we can see that this inequality $\det\left(Y+Z\right) \geq \det Y + \det Z$ also holds when $Y$ and $Z$ are both positive semidefinite (rather than $Y$ being positive definite and $Z$ positive semidefinite).

Comment: Thank you,It's Nice too!+1

Answer (score 0):

All eigenvalues of $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative since $X,Y \in \mathbb{S}^{n}_+$.
We use the fact that $\forall i \in \{1,2,3,...,n\},$ we have $\lambda_i(X)\geq \lambda_i(Y).$ See [page 46 here](http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ewkma/engg5781/notes/lecture%204-%20PSD.pdf).

Then $\det(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(X)\geq \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(Y)=\det(Y)$.