# Show that $det \left( {A+B} \right) \geq det\left( {A} \right)$

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant, positive-definite

Let $A$ is a positive define symmetric matrix,and $B$ is a semi-positive definite symmetric matrix. Does $$det \left( {A+B} \right) \geq det\left( {A} \right)$$ hold? Could someone help me with this, thank you.

Comment: sorry, a mistake in my last comment, and see  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65424/determinant-of-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices

Comment: It does not matter,thanks anyhow.

Comment: Similar question [posted recently](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087301/how-to-prove-that-detab-deta-detb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I have answered a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1101184/59379) before, no wonder I have a feeling of "déjà vu".
Look at answers in that question if you find the answer below too terse.

---

Since $A$ is positive definite, it has a positive definite invertible square root $S = A^{1/2}$.  We have the breakdown $$\det(A+B) = \det(A)\det(I+ C)$$
where $C = S^{-1/2}BS^{-1/2}$.

Since $B$ is positive semi-definite and symmetric, so do $C$. If we choose a basis to diagonalize $C$, we find its eigenvalues are all non-negative. This implies $\det(I+C) \ge 1$ and we are done.